# Alteration Services vs Tailoring

Tags: vocabulary

Alteration services and tailoring. Are they different or same?
I get results where businesses offer combine them but I cannot seem to discern any tangible differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both will alter existing clothing, though at least in my experience, a tailor will usually also be able to create garments for you. So if I wanted some suit pants let out, I could go to either, but if I wanted some suit pants made, I would have to find a tailor.